# Странное поведение исключений в Form_Load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net, отладка

Если в обработчике события `Load` происходит исключение, то при запуске из VS оно не отображается - просто прерывается выполнение метода и отображается форма. Это происходит как при запуске, так и при пошаговой отладке.

В предыдущих версиях VS эту проблему решало создание новой конфигурации билда под x64. Хотя, приходилось выставлять Empty в качестве базовой, что само по себе неудобно, т. к. приходится заново настраивать уровни предупреждений.

Но в VS2015 что-то ничего хорошего не получается. Что делать?

[Скринвидео проблемы](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2gj3ewrXbp5S/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20Form_Load.wmv) (27MB).

PS: Нашёл несколько таких вопросов на enSO, но там либо жуткие костыли, либо описание того, что это связано с 32-битностью приложения.

Comment: Вот интересная статья на эту тему https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/976038

Comment: @Dmitry, ---------------------------
Автономный установщик обновлений Windows
---------------------------
Обновление не применимо к этому комьютеру.


---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------

Или надо руками создавать? А поможет?

Comment: Думаю стоит поискать подобное решение именно для вашей системы. Список систем обновляемых данным обновлением не очень широк к сожаленю

Comment: @Dmitry, у меня Win7 x64 - там в перечисленных была.

Comment: Да, действительно, есть такая. А еще какие-то ошибки есть или только эта?

Comment: реестр правили?

Comment: @Dmitry, нет. Я ожидал, что обновление именно это и делает.

Comment: попробуйте руками по реестру пройтись, а потом еще раз попытайтесь установить обновление

Comment: А это случайно не связано с политикой обработки unobserved exceptions? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx

Comment: @VladD, в моём коде Task же вообще нет. Кстати, с тасками как раз исключения работают, хотя я читал, что не должны. Ты скринвидео смотрел?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, смотрел. У меня есть подозрение, что в базовом `OnLoad` стоит `catch { /*ignore*/ }`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: С тасками можно конфигурировать. И на мой вкус это ужасно, т. к. поведение должно быть жёстко определено языком: имею я право тупо Cancel'ить ненужные таски, или после этого мне нужно ещё ловить TaskCanceledException? Поменял конфигурацию, и код не валиден — ыыыыы!

Comment: Есть радикальное решение данной проблемы: используйте явный перехват всех исключений `try catch` в "точках входа" в вашем приложении.

Comment: @ZverevEugene, зачем он мне?

Comment: @Qwertiy "Он" вам затем, чтобы ваше приложение штатно вело себя при возникновении исключений. Штатно закрывалось, а не через исключение. Даже в "маленьких" и "внутренних" приложениях, которые кроме вас самого никто не увидит, это нужно для самодисциплины. Воспитание в себе дисциплины это субъективный вопрос, я не спорю, но решение работает совершенно объективно.

Comment: @ZverevEugene, мне нужно, чтобы VS остановилась на исключении и я мог дебажить код в месте возникновения исключения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Прошу прощения, не врубился с ходу в суть вопроса. Предлагаю два решения проблемы ниже.

Answer (score 3):

**1. [Первый вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11997142/119527) из англоязычного SO. Кратенько копирую:**

Добавляем класс для вызова потребных функций:

```
public static class Kernel32
{
    public const uint PROCESS_CALLBACK_FILTER_ENABLED = 0x1;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy(UInt32 dwFlags);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy(out UInt32 lpFlags);


    public static void DisableUMCallbackFilter() {
        uint flags;
        GetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy(out flags);

        flags &= ~PROCESS_CALLBACK_FILTER_ENABLED;
        SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy(flags);
    }
}
```

Вызываем это всё на старте приложения:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Kernel32.DisableUMCallbackFilter();
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

**2. Второй вариант - разорвать негодный контекст вызова Form_Load:**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            //Форме рано представать перед пользователем.
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

            Task.Run(
                delegate
                {
                    //Это нужно, чтобы успеть посмотреть, как процесс
                    //загрузки будет выглядеть для пользователя.
                    //Thread.Sleep(3000);

                    this.Invoke(
                        new Action(delegate
                        {
                            FormLoadLogic();

                            //Теперь можно форму показать.
                            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                        }));
                });
        }
        else
        {
            FormLoadLogic();
        }
    }

    FormLoadLogic()
    {
        this.Text = "step 1";
        throw new Exception("test");
        this.Text = "step 2";
    }
```

Comment: Но ведь эти костыли останутся в коде, хотя при запуске без VS они не нужны. Хотелось бы как-то отладчик заставить правильно работать без костылей в коде.

Comment: @Qwertiy Костыли можно убрать через проверку режима работы. Сейчас впишу.

Comment: `#if DEBUG` расставить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не люблю `#IF DEBUG` поскольку сам часто использую сборки, откомпилированные в `Debug`, в продукционной среде. Я предпочитаю `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`. Я прописал это всё в коде, посмотрите.

Comment: `#if DEBUG` будет выкинуто при компиляции, а проверка на дебаггер будет исполняться каждый раз и оставит код в приложении.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну если хотите - замените на `#IF DEBUG`, но это мнимая оптимизация. С точки зрения производительности, проверка эта не стоит ровным счётом ничего. А вот забыть поменять конфигурацию с `Debug` на `Release` перед перекомпиляцией очень легко. Признайтесь честно, есть у вас система, которая проверяет, что сборки, публикуемые в продукционную среду, откомпилированы в конфигурации `Release`? Я вам помогу. Нет у вас такой системы. У меня такая система есть. Например, подготовка выкладки у меня отнимает 2 часа. Получаю предупреждение, сборки - в `Debug`. Я переделываю всё? Ну конечно же нет!

Comment: WinForms-приложение делаю только для себя, соответственно они достаточно мелкие, а системы автосборки нет. Но если бы была, она бы сама собирала в нужной конфигурации и от меня бы это не зависело. msbuild может принимать ключ командной строки для сборки в нужном режиме - его и надо использовать на CI-сервере.

Comment: @Qwertiy Зайду с другой стороны. Если вы хотите изменить поведение  обработки ошибок именно в процессе отладки - правильно использовать `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`. Если вам надо  внедрить альтернативную ветку кода для конфигурации `Debug` - используйте `IF #DEBUG`. Я в коде оставляю первый вариант, так как вы объяснили задачу так: "чтобы VS остановилась на исключении и я мог дебажить код в месте возникновения исключения".