# Исключение при попытке закрыть форму с браузером

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser

Есть форма с единственным контролом типа WebBrowser.
Для обработки нажатия <kbd>Ecs</kbd> используется [переопределение `ProcessCmdKey`](/a/480925/178988).
При загрузке формы выполняется открытие стараницы в `webBrowser1`.

Вот код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
  {
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
      this.Close();
      return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
  }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии <kbd>Esc</kbd> форма закрывается, но приложение падает:

> RaceOnRCWCleanup occurred
>
> Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'RaceOnRCWCleanup' has detected a problem in 'C:\Тут был путь к проекту\bin\Release\Test - Close by Esc with WebBrowser.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: Была предпринята попытка освободить RCW, находящийся в использовании. RCW используется активным потоком или другим потоком. Попытка освободить RCW, находящийся в использовании, может привести к повреждению или потере данных.

Стектрейс показывается такой:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.__ComObject.FinalReleaseSelf()  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(object o) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionFromLoadedToPassive()    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionDownTo(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserHelper.AXState state)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Dispose(bool disposing)    Unknown
    System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(bool disposing)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(bool disposing)  Unknown
>   Test - Close by Esc with WebBrowser.exe!Test___Close_by_Esc_with_WebBrowser.Form1.Dispose(bool disposing) Line 21   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(int msg, int wparam, int lparam)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()  Unknown
    Test - Close by Esc with WebBrowser.exe!Test___Close_by_Esc_with_WebBrowser.Form1.ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData) Line 25    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.PreProcessMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control target, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserSiteBase.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleControlSite.TranslateAccelerator(ref System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG pMsg, int grfModifiers)   Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.PreProcessMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(System.Windows.Forms.Control target, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG msg) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG msg) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown
    Test - Close by Esc with WebBrowser.exe!Test___Close_by_Esc_with_WebBrowser.Program.Main() Line 20  C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/q/1874496/5796587

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34383/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy-------).

Answer (score 4):

Это не ошибка, это лишь предупреждение, выдаваемое Managed Debugging Assistant'ом (это такое расширение отладчика), которому кажется, что с вашим кодом что-то не так. Вы используете Runtime Callable Wrapper, специальную обёртку для COM-контролов (`WebBrowser` по сути является COM-контролом).

Когда вы пытаетесь закрыть форму, расширение отладчика бросается на амбразуру и заявляет вам, что браузер ещё используется, а вы убиваете его до того, как его текущая функция полностью отработает. Такое может по идее привести к реальным проблемам лишь если ваш код многопоточный.

---

Проблема воспроизводится в обычном коде при использовании `CancelProperty` у кнопки, или `DialogResult`. Или в вашем случае, когда у вас есть особая реакция на Esc. Фокус находится на `WebBrowser`'е, он получает нажатие Esc. Обвязка ActiveX собирается сообщить контейнеру о нажатии, чтобы он мог на него отреагировать. (Это нужно, например, для поддержки клавиатурных шорткатов, Tab'а, Enter/Escape для активизации кнопок и тому подобного.) Если при этом нажатие на клавишу *закрывает* форму (как в вашем случае), отладчик видит, что на `WebBrowser`'е вызывается `Dispose` в то время как код его RCW ещё выполняется. Опасность заключается в том, что когда код вернётся в RCW, он имеет право работать с COM-объектом (он же не знает, что у него из под носа этот самый объект увели), и произойдёт вылет — это не такой уж и редкий сценарий.

Окей, в конкретно данном случае вылет вроде бы не воспроизводится так просто. Но по идее проблема может произойти если финализирующий поток доберётся до COM-объекта *до того*, как произойдёт возврат из обработчика Esc. Так что у нач возможна гонка между UI-потоком и потоком финализатора.

В качестве заплатки можно отложить реальное закрытие на момент, когда код обвязки ActiveX закончит работу. Например, вызывая закрытие асинхронно:

```
if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)this.Close);
    return true;
}
```

---

<sub>Вольный перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1874496/5796587) с en.SO</sub>

Comment: `this.BeginInvoke((Action)this.Close);` же. Зачем мудрить?

Comment: это какая-то древняя проблема. я проверял в VS 2015, даже если в DocumentCompleted указать `this.ActiveControl = wb; wb.Focus();`, то форма не падает.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Копипаст :) Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Да, работает через `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @Stack: В ответе написано, что падает код редко, т. к. гонка с финализатором.

Comment: Перекопипаст, надо дочистить)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если видите где-то лишнее, правьте, ответ всё равно общий!

Comment: @Stack, фокус всегда у браузера - других контролов нет.

Comment: @VladD _"т. к. гонка с финализатором."_ -- в сообщении об ошибке видно, это не финализатор. там вызывается WmClose, затем Form.Dispose ... WebBrowser.Dispose и т.д. скорее всего там баг в TransitionFromLoadedToPassive

Comment: @Stack: Ну, ответ вроде бы говорит, что без студии исключения не будет, а будет гонка. Исключение именно для того, чтобы обратить внимание на гонку. (Сам не пробовал.)

Answer (score 1):

Базовый метод ProcessCmdKey надо **вызывать до вызова Close**.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    var res = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
        this.Close();
        res = true;
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Иначе, если base.ProcessCmdKey вызывается после закрытия формы, то надо удалять браузер перед закрытием.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
   if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
       this.Controls.Remove(wb);   // ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТУ СТРОКУ
       this.Close();
       return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Проверил в Visual Studio Community 2015, C# Interactive

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.WIndows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form {
    WebBrowser wb;
    public Form1() {
        wb = new WebBrowser() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = this };
        wb.Navigating += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Navigating " + e.Url);
        wb.Navigated += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Navigated " + e.Url);
        wb.DocumentCompleted += delegate { Console.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted"); };
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) {
            this.Controls.Remove(wb);   // ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТУ СТРОКУ
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        wb.Navigate("about:blank");
    }
}

var f = new Form1();
f.Activated += delegate { SendKeys.Send("{ESC}"); };
f.ShowDialog();
```

Работает нормально, закрывается при нажатии Esc и выводит

```
Navigating about:blank
Navigated about:blank
DocumentCompleted
```

Comment: Эм.. А `base.OnLoad` кто вызывать будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy _"А base.OnLoad кто вызывать будет?"_ -- забыл :) но и с base.OnLoad не падает.

Comment: `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
      webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
      base.OnLoad(e);
    }` - у меня падает. Может не будешь раскладывать формы по консольным приложениям?

Comment: @Qwertiy _"Может не будешь раскладывать формы по консольным приложениям?"_ -- C# Interactive - это не консольное приложение. в нем любой тип приложений создается. и WPF тоже.

Comment: Не обратил внимание. А вот на `Console.WriteLine` обратил. Меня нормальные winforms интересуют.

Comment: @Qwertiy _OnLoad(EventArgs e) { webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank"); base.OnLoad(e); }"_ -- лучше OnLoad убрать. а вызов webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank"); перенести в конструктор формы.

Comment: @Qwertiy _"на Console.WriteLine обратил"_ -- вывод идет прямо в окно C# Interactive. вполне удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант решения - подписаться на `PreviewKeyDown` самого `WebBrowser`а:

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что подписка на нажатие клавиши на форме не работает, независимо от значения свойства `KeyPreview`. Нужно именно на браузер.

Comment: Это решение по идее должно страдать от того же race condition'а? (Не уверен.)

Comment: а если в Form.ProcessCmdKey перед this.Close(); вызвать webBrowser1.Dispose(); тоже падает?

Comment: @Stack так тоже падает.

Comment: @VladD, подписка же не на форму, а в самом контроле. Возможно, это имеет значение. Но так не падает. Ну или [падает молча](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/480464/178988) - сегодня замучался с этой гадостью...